# How do I emulate a data layer in memory without giving program wide access?

Tags: java

I'm revisiting a school project where you have a simple java console program that takes a space delimited file to populate an array of objects in memory and also allow the user to perform CRUD operations on the data stored.

I've created a basic MVC pattern which implement command patterns to communicate CRUD commands between the controller and the data. I've also created a repository class when instantiated that holds all the objects in memory.

How should I give access to the classes that needs to know about the repository instance?

Comment: If you are using MVC with separated layers, you need to look into Inversion of Control and dependency injection. I would recommend Guice for a small project, as it's a little more lightweight than Spring.

Comment: @BoristheSpider or you could just pass the reference to the components which need it in Java, even more light weight ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I've found that whenever I tried to do that, even for a small project, it quickly got very messy...

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have always found frameworks to be messer than just writing Java code to do the same thing. Easier to debug and refactor too. ;) +1 though.

Comment: @PeterLawrey horses for courses...

Answer (score 2):

You give access by passing a reference to the data layer just as you would for any other object.

I suggest you avoid making the object `static` i.e. globally accessible. Use Dependency Injection instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for a dependency injection pattern.

Lets say you have a controller class and a repository class which implements a CRUD style interface then your controller constructor takes a single argument of the interface type. Whatever creates the controller, be that an application or a web-framework (like Spring-MVC), can then pass in an instance of the concrete repository type. In unit tests it should be easy enough to create the controller with a fake or mock repository.

Example:

```
public interface Repository {
  MyItem getAnItem(int id);
  void updateItem(MyItem item);
}

public class SqlBackedRepository implements Repository {
  @Override
  public MyItem getAnItem(int id) {
      sqldb.execSql("select item...");
  }
}

public class MyItemController {
  private final Repository repository;
  public MyItemController(Repository repository) {
  ...
  }

  public doControlThing() {
      final MyItem item = repository.getItem();
      item.doStuff();
      repository.updateItem(item);
  }
}
```

and so on.

There's lots of DI frameworks out there - Spring, Guice, Dagr, Weld, ... Which one to use depends a lot on your use case and personal preferences.

Comment: Beautifully simple example - welcome to Stack Overflow.